# Yii2 Rest Doesn't Update using JQUERY AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, yii2, yii-rest

! , 
I'm Working On An Application that using JQUERY AJAX to CRUD data ,
In the Server side I'm using Yii2 framework , so I'm working with its rest.
But The Error Is That it doesn't update any data and it returns the same old data
There the JS Code

```
$.ajax({
        url:"rest/jobs/1"
        type: "PUT",
        data: {job:"Assistant"},
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,

    })
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .fail(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

RESPONSE :

```
{id: "1", job: "old data"}
```

Comment: show your controller code

Comment: It was generated using gii controller so you can review this

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html#trying-it-out

Comment: I would recommend checking your model validation rules and check for validation errors before trying to find something wrong with the code.

Comment: it works well on the normal controller not the rest so rules is simply work well and validation too but i don't know to answer